# Send image in :before pseudo element behind of element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I was inspired by [Multiple Backgrounds with single element](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/) and try to do that...but failed.

This is my sample code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Reiot/E8HAe/).

Image(blue bird) in the :before element never goes down to main(white bird) element. Here goes what I tried with :before.

- content:url() or background:url()
- z-index: -1 or arbitrary smaller number than main's
- :before and :after :(

How can I send it back to main element???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first link the schema shows :before and :after backgrounds are on the element's background??
So I think all's good, you just have to invert the two backgrounds.

Comment: Oh. I understand what you said.. never think about it.. :)